# how to get parameter from query string in ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have some problem on getting parameter from query string. I'm trying using

> import { URLSearchParams } from
>   '@angular/http';
>
> this.params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
>   this.params1 = this.params.getAll('param');
>   console.log('parameter: '+JSON.stringify(this.params1))

and when I'm try to access `http://localhost:8100/param=1` it getting error `Cannot GET /param=1`

How can I get that param?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, i'm try using `this.platform.getQueryParam('param');` and it working fine.